# Can't read Comixology comics purchased on my Kindle Fire since app update

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

Since the Comixology Android app update a few days ago, I've been unable to read any comics that I had previously purchased on my Kindle Fire. The app tells me that the device is not authorized to read these comics. I'm directed to sign in, but I'm already signed in on that device with my Comixology account.

I saw on their Facebook page that they have some work-arounds to try, but they don't list them anywhere on their site.  How can I read comics in the updated Comixology app that I had purchased before the update?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try before contacting [Comixology support](http://www.comixology.com/contact-us).

1. Go to the Settings of the Comixology app, and then tap the Restore Purchases button. That might solve things if you're logged into your comiXology account.
2. If that doesn't work, you can go to the Purchases section of the app and Read from there. Click on the Comixology icon in the top left corner of the app to view the menu to switch from Featured, Publishers, Purchases, etc.  Once you're on the Purchases screen, click on a book, then click the Read button.
3. The final solution to try would be to re-install the Comixology app.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was: the comics that you see in my books on your Comixology account in a web browser and don't see in the app, try archiving them and then extracting them. You can archive them by pressing "..." on the selected comic Archive series, going to the archive,  selecting the same comic and pressing remove from archive. Takes a bit of time but at least it's something.